# React navigation TabNavigator resets to default route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've a strange thing happening in my navigation. I've a tab navigator with home as a default tab and Profile as another tab. When I try to upload an image from profile tab using fetch and formData it automatically redirects back to home tab. I tried to call a simple api w/o formData and it did not redirect.
This happens w/o setting any state, calling redux actions or anything. Just after the AJAX call.

```
uploadImage(fileToBeUploaded, imagePath) {
let data = new FormData();
data.append("userId", this.props.userData._id);
data.append("file", fileToBeUploaded);
fetch(Metrics.serverUrl + "users/updateUserInformation", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.props.token,
    'userid': this.props.userData._id,
  },
  body: data
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    if (responseJson.status) {
      console.log(responseJson);
      return;
```